# Histogram expand zoom using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

Have a reusable histogram [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kxnj23s1/)
What I want is ability to expand (zoom) by clicking on a particular bar, so the x axis updates and I can see more detailed view for a smaller range. I've already have a click event so how it can be modified to achieve the expand functionality?

```
        bar.append("rect")
            .attr("x", 1)
            .attr("width", barWidth)
            .attr("height", function (d) {
            return maxBarHeight - y(d.y);
        })
            .on("click", function () {
              console.log("clicked");
        });
```

Comment: Are you hoping for a zoom in animation or is an instant effect appropriate for your use case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zooming bar-graph with d3.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126207/zooming-bar-graph-with-d3-js)